# Python, flask, android app

Tags: android, python, sql, flask

I would like to make an android app and it will need to access a database on a remote server. I have read that I will need to use flask and set up a Rest Api. I am bit confused what that the point of that actually is? If I use the API does that mean that I will only be able to read data, or can I add to the database as well? In that case why is it such a bad idea for the users to write to the database directly from the app? I can't see how that is any different. Is the password not enough security? Many thanks for your help.

Comment: How could the app write directly to the database? You said yourself, it's on a remote server. That's what an API is, it accepts remote reads and writes to the database.

Comment: In the API you can setup what you want to be available to the public Read/Write  and include the logic you need and only that. If you give password to all your user they can do whatever they want to your db, not too secure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An API can definitely read and write to a database. It basically provides a way for your users to access your server in a deliberate and controlled manner. Anything you can do on your server can be exposed via API methods. What you expose is up to you.

The API provides a layer of error handling and protection from inputs that you want to offer to all users, regardless of whether they are authorized to make those updates. For example, they may mistakingly add a null value or an incorrect type for a parameter, which you can catch and raise an exception for in your API.

Additionally, if you are trying to make updates on a remote server, providing a REST HTTP API provides one of the more lean methods for accessing and performing requests on that server. APIs like this are what many of the mobile applications you are used to using rely on for remote functionality.

If you want to get started creating and standing up an API very quickly and are not tied to Flask (although Flask is fantastic and also has some great [tutorials](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/tutorial/)), you can also try out [Google App Engine for Python](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/) to get the hang of things.

Comment: Thanks for your help, that was really helpful. Much appreciated :)